# Как добавить таб в контекстное меню расширения Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Как добавить еще один `option` в контекстное меню, которое вызывается правым кликом по иконке расширения?

Пробую это

```
function addMenu(title) {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        title: title,
        contexts: ["all"],
        onclick: function() { console.log(1)}
    });
}

addMenu('Log out');
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running contextMenus.create: Extensions using event pages must pass an id parameter to chrome.contextMenus.create

Кто с такими задачами сталкивался? Можете помочь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из документации

> If you're using the context menus API, pass a string id parameter to
>   contextMenus.create, and use the contextMenus.onClicked callback
>   instead of an onclick parameter to contextMenus.create.

Полагаю надо передать ID

```
function addMenu(title) {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        id: 'my-id', // сюда
        title: title,
        contexts: ["all"],
        onclick: function() { console.log(1)}
    });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, callback удалось так сделать
     chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function() {
          console.log('1');
     });